# how to prohibit iframe jump the another website

Tags: html, iframe

**1.** Below is my HTML code:
http://jsbin.com/fafuduyene/edit?html,output

**2.** What I want to do: I want to embed my chinese blog into my own website, and make it look like a part of my web page, which means I can totally operate it on my web page.

**3.** What the problem is: The blog itself seems to set some rules to forbid me to operate the blog directly from my web page. When I click the iframe, it will always jump to the blog web page. How can I do to cancel this jump?

Comment: Hi and welcome to SO! Please read [this](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) post for how to ask better questions, which will help people give you better answers. In particular, it's better not to keep all your code in a link, as links tend to break over time rendering the question unhelpful to future readers.

Comment: What you're trying to accomplish, others would consider to be stealing content and bandwidth. While it may be your own content you're using, the general case is somebody trying to use content that doesn't belong to them. Thus protections are in place.